# animsition plugin keeps on preloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, animsition

I started using animsition today and everything looked simple at first. However, when I used it on my html code, the animsition wouldn't work and it kept on preloading.

Html body

```
<div class="panel1">
  <div class="tex">text</div><div class="t">t</div>
  <div class="animsition head">
    <h2>Something</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".animsition").animsition({
inClass: 'fade-in-up',
outClass: 'fade-out-up',
inDuration: 1500,
outDuration: 800,
linkElement: '.animsition-link',
// e.g. linkElement: 'a:not([target="_blank"]):not([href^="#"])'
loading: true,
loadingParentElement: 'body', //animsition wrapper element
loadingClass: 'animsition-loading',
loadingInner: '', // e.g '<img src="loading.svg" />'
timeout: false,
timeoutCountdown: 5000,
onLoadEvent: true,
browser: [ 'animation-duration', '-webkit-animation-duration'],
// "browser" option allows you to disable the "animsition" in case the css property in the array is not supported by your browser.
// The default setting is to disable the "animsition" in a browser that does not support "animation-duration".
overlay : false,
overlayClass : 'animsition-overlay-slide',
overlayParentElement : 'body',
transition: function(url){ window.location.href = url; }
});
```

And the browser displays a preloader which never completes loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!
Animsition doesn't work with the latest version of jquery(3.1.1). So beware, animsition users.

Comment: Man you saved my day!

Comment: After reading your answer, I found out `v2.2.4` is the latest jQuery version it does work with.